# currentbuttonstatus

Tags: arduino-mega, button

I'm trying to use momentary push buttons to switch bi color LED between RED and GREEN. I've got one working, but when I try to adapt the code for more buttons, it doesn't work. I'm just changing the buttonnumbers (which are defined).
It compiles and uploads without error.

```
void loop() {
  byte currentButton1Status = digitalRead(button1);
  if (currentButton1Status == button1Status)
    lastEqualButtonTime = millis();
  else if ((millis() - lastEqualButtonTime) > debounceTimeMs)
  {
    lastEqualButtonTime = millis();
    button1Status = currentButton1Status;

    if (button1Status == LOW) {
      digitalWrite(17, !digitalRead(17));
      digitalWrite(16, !digitalRead(16));
    }
  }

  byte currentButton2Status = digitalRead(button2);
  if (currentButton2Status == button2Status)
    lastEqualButtonTime = millis();
  else if ((millis() - lastEqualButtonTime) > debounceTimeMs)
  {
    lastEqualButtonTime = millis();
    button2Status = currentButton2Status;

    if (button2Status == LOW) {
      digitalWrite(15, !digitalRead(15));
      digitalWrite(14, !digitalRead(14));
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: please post the complete code .... the way it is right now, there are a few definitions missing

Comment: You might want to look into using a debounce library  e.g. https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce2

Comment: `it doesn't work` is not a good problem description

Comment: Use serial print to debug...

Comment: @chrisl there's nothing more to it. If I have the "byte currentButton...." just for button one, it works. If I use it the way I've posted above everything compiles and uploads ok, but when I press any of the two buttons, nothing happens.

Comment: @jsotola Everything is defined and I didn't want to bother you guys with other stuff that didn't have to do anything with this problem.

Comment: @user31208, you posted a partial program, so there is no way to confirm that the code compiles, and there is no way to pinpoint the failure

Comment: They can't all use the same variable, lastEqualButtonTime, to keep up with debouncing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only said "... it doesn't work" which doesn't give much to go on, but the first thing I see that might contribute it not working as (I think) you expect it o, is only one `lastEqualButtonTime` variable for both buttons (is it a global? I don't see a definition). I think you'll need one for each.